# Angular Dynamic Field in form not showing in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamicform

This is baffling. It is such a simple thing, but I'm not able to get it to work. I am adding an input field to the form on a button click (originally). At this point I'm just trying to see any value in the view (hence the simple p tag)

HTML VIEW

```
<span>Add secondary field</span>
<md-button class="md-fab md-mini" ng-click="vm.addVals()">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</md-button>

<div ng-if="moreVal">
    <div data-ng-repeat="vl in valHolder.valArr track by $index">
    <p>My Value: {{vl.myVal}}</p>
</div>
```

Controller

```
 function EditFormController($scope, $sanitize, ngToast) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.addVals = addVals;
  $scope.valHolder= {valArr: []};
  function addVals(){
   var ln = $scope.valHolder.valArr.length;
   $scope.valHolder.valArr.push({myVal: 'Test'+ln});  
   $scope.moreVal = true;
  }
 }());
```

I have checked that valArr is being populated with new myVal values on button click. But I cannot see anything in the View. the ng-repeat div is empty. Why is this happening? I have been searching for a solution all day now, but this is so absurd no one seems to have this issue. Don't know what I'm doing wrong. I would really appreciate an answer.

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: Do you use controller as syntax in view ? Can you please show your whole HTML code ?

Comment: @Mistalis No error in the console

Comment: @Ankit Vadi Yes I am, but it seems not for this function. Could that be it?

Comment: @AnkitVadi You were correct, the use of $scope, when I'm using the controller as syntax in view is what was causing the error. Please write this as the answer so I can select it. Thank you.

Comment: I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code in your controller:

```
var self = this;
self.valHolder= {valArr: []};
function addVal(){
  var ln = self.valHolder.valArr.length;
  self.valHolder.valArr.push({myVal: 'Test'+ln});  
  self.moreVal = true;
}
```

Write in your HTML like below:

```
<div ng-if="moreVal">
    <div data-ng-repeat="vl in vm.valHolder.valArr track by $index">
    <p>My Value: {{vl.myVal}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be self.valHolder.valArr in the HTML?

Comment: No, you are using your syntax like ng-controller="EditFormController as vm" right ? Then in your view self will be reffered as vm. Or if you are defining in route it would be like controlller: "EditFormController" and controllerAs: "vm"

Comment: Actually I'm not, I have only specified ng-controller="EditFormController" and it seems to work just fine. Not sure if I'm missing something here. Still learning the ropes with Angular so excuse the ignorance.

Comment: You have written var vm = this; and I have written var self = this;. So basically vm and self both points to same object. If vm works fine in view, you can use vm too, because ultimately both are same objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your addVal function is not getting called. Please change your HTML view to this-

```
<span>Add secondary field</span>
<md-button class="md-fab md-mini" ng-click="addVal()">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</md-button>

<div ng-if="moreVal">
    <div data-ng-repeat="vl in valHolder.valArr track by $index">
    <p>My Value: {{vl.myVal}}</p>
</div>
```

and Controller code to this-

```
 $scope.valHolder = { valArr: [] };
 $scope.addVal = function () {
    var ln = $scope.valHolder.valArr.length;
    $scope.valHolder.valArr.push({ myVal: 'Test' + ln });
    $scope.moreVal = true;
 }
```

In case you are using ControllerAs syntax and you have specified controllerAs:"vm", then your code will be below

```
<span>Add secondary field</span>
<md-button class="md-fab md-mini" ng-click="vm.addVal()">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</md-button>

<div ng-if="vm.moreVal">
    <div data-ng-repeat="vl in vm.valHolder.valArr track by $index">
    <p>My Value: {{vl.myVal}}</p>
</div>
```

and Controller code to this-

```
var self = this;
 self.valHolder = { valArr: [] };
 self.addVal = function () {
    var ln = self.valHolder.valArr.length;
    self.valHolder.valArr.push({ myVal: 'Test' + ln });
    self.moreVal = true;
 }
```

Comment: addVal function is being called. This was a typo on my part. Sorry. I was debugging with console statements and I know that valArr is being populated correctly. The problem is only with the view not showing anything.

Comment: I just tried it at my end and the solution which I gave is working. have you added $scope.addVal = function() { ... } in your controller code

Comment: Please find my updated answer incase you are using controllerAs syntax

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, Ankit Vadi got to the answer first, so have awarded him the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ng-click="vm.addVals()"` and `$scope` in controller.

I think you should use `var vm` in controller as well. Add these lines:

```
var vm = this;
vm = {};
```

and

```
vm.addVals = addVals;
```

Comment: I agree this conflict is what led to the problem, but Ankit Vadi got to the answer first. Thanks